# how to specify the scope with oauth2 client application

Tags: spring-security-oauth2, oauth2client, spring-boot-starter-oauth2-client

I am using Spring Security OAuth2 client application and have provided the below configuration

```
spring:
  security:
    oauth2:
      client:
        registration:
          okta:
            client-id: 
            client-secret: 
            scope: openid
        provider:
          okta:
            authorization-uri: https://dev-7858070.okta.com/oauth2/default/v1/authorize
            token-uri: https://dev-7858070.okta.com/oauth2/default/v1/token
            user-info-uri: https://dev-7858070.okta.com/oauth2/default/v1/userinfo
            jwk-set-uri: https://dev-7858070.okta.com/oauth2/default/v1/keys
```

I have specified the scope to only `openid`, but still getting other scopes like `profile` and `email`. I want to just get the openid scope. Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can specify multiple scopes by separating them with a comma.

```yaml
spring:
  security:
    oauth2:
      client:
        registration:
          okta:
            client-id: 
            client-secret: 
            scope: openid,profile,email
```

Comment: Why was this the correct answer? It's exact opposite of what the question asked

Comment: I think the question might've been different when I first answered it. That's the only explanation I can think of.

Answer (score 0):

In OAuth2 authorization systems it is possible to define default scopes for a client. The client will always get these scopes, even if it didn‘t request them.

Profile and email are typical default scopes.